# How to get latest all Wikipedia article titles sorted by pageview ranking?

Tags: wikipedia, wikimedia, wikimedia-dumps

Here's the link to the latest list of Wikipedia's article titles:

https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/latest/enwiki-latest-all-titles-in-ns0.gz

But the list is sorted by article titles (from 0-9, A-Z, ...). Now I want the list sorted by pageview ranking. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the [pageview dumps](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pageviews/2019/2019-01/), load them into a database, process them (they are split by hour and include all Wikimedia projects so you'll probably want to filter and aggregate), and use that for sorting.